# Spring Boot Integration Testing - Port Bound

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I'm trying to write a Spring Boot integration test for a microservice I've written.  The microservices runs on port 8888.

This is my test class:

```
import com.mydomain.app.MyAPI;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyAPI.class}, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MyIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

When I run the test without starting the microservice the test method passes fine - the context loads.  The problem is when I start the microservice then run the test.  I get an error saying that port 8888 is already in use.  I understand that it's in use because the microservice is bound to the port but I don't understand why WebEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT hasn't assigned a different port to the test sever than 8888.

Can anyone assist please?

Comment: can you share the error stacktrace

Comment: Have you tried checking the value of `server.port` during the test?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue by changing the RANDOM_PORT option to DEFINED_PORT.  This forced Spring Boot to use a port specified in a configuration file.  For some reason, I'm unsure why, the RANDOM_PORT option was continually opting to use 8888 even though it was in use.